# Convert code blocks to backtick syntax when converting answers to comments

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, convert-to-comment

If an answer has an indented code block, if it's converted to a comment, the formatting is ignored, leaving just plain text "code".

It would be better if the indented code was wrapped in backticks to retain formatting that will work in a comment.

Concrete example, if a post is:

---

Try changing:

```
int i = a + b;
```

to:

```
int i = a - b;
```

---

If converted to a comment, would look like:

> Try changing: `int i = a + b;` to: `int i = a - b;`

---

Although noting that answers with lots of code are unlikely candidates for conversion to comments, multi-line blocks could be handled easily if the language had line terminators (like `;` of c-like languages) eg:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
    doX(a[i]);
    doY(a[i+1]);
}
```

Would be convert legibly: `for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) { doX(a[i]); doY(a[i+1]);}`

Languages without line terminators I'm sure could be handled in *some* way (TBA).

Comment: This wouldn't work for multi-line code blocks though.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy it would work OK for languages that use line terminators (like `;` in c-like) and even if not you could backtick each line separately, like `line 1`...`line 2` etc to give more visual space, and answers with lots of lines in a code block are unlikely to be converted anyway.